# How can I use a GUI on a supercomputer?

Tags: vasp, high-performance-computing, python, visualization-software, graphical-user-interface

I am trying to make plots based to [VASP](https://www.vasp.at/) simulation results, but I am struggling with how to download so much data from the server. A lot of examples on the internet are taught using the local desktop environment, which has a GUI like [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/). They could use Python to make plots easily, but when I need to run some serious simulation, I would like to do it on an HPC cluster, which doesn't have a GUI.

**Do I have to download all the data to my laptop, or are there some other solutions?**

Comment: If you are looking for simple GUI to interface with your HPC cluster a simple solution could be to use WebMO(https://www.webmo.net/). Its pretty good for molecular systems and can be interfaced with many ab-initio software that are installed on your cluster. (I never tried it for materials  extensively but I guess it should work with VASP and Espresso)

Comment: WebMO helps with managing jobs you submit and to a good extent with visualization. If you have output in text files(or .dat files), you could use gnuplot for plotting. To post process your data, you could use python(jupyter notebooks hosted on your server itself, more power!)

Comment: If you are not comfortable with terminal, may be you could try using VSCode and ssh to your cluster. That way you could open and see your text file easily in the editor. Also, you could use it also for writing jupyter notebook or any other post processing tools.

Comment: @EverydayFoolish why don't you write an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure, if that helps. Though question says GUI on supercomputer most answers and discussions in this thread have been about many other things. But, @Jack do you think WebMO or any of the other tools might be relevant to your question?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. But I can't persuade the HPC adviser to install this software, could I install and use it as a normal user?

Comment: @EverydayFoolish I agree with Nike, these comments are probably better collected into an answer.

Comment: @EverydayFoolish Comments are "[temporary post-it notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)" and are typically deleted permanently (you have no way to get them back). Also answering in comments is extremely highly discouraged. The follow-up question by the OP should have been a comment on your answer, rather than a comment on their own question. We'll leave your comments here for a while so that you can access them when writing your answer (if you want!), but they might not last here for long.

Comment: @Jack To use WebMO as an interface with your HPC cluster, its better that admin installs it for you and makes it available for you on your remote instance. Usually, the cluster is insulated from the internet to prevent attacks, so to install it yourself, you would have to upload and install all the dependencies yourself. You can create an Apache2 server (for a remote linux instance) and then install webmo on it. See this : https://www.webmo.net/support/instructions.html

Comment: @NikeDattani I will try to write a more comprehensive answer on the weekend, mostly basing it on my comments on WebMO.

Comment: Many supercomputer center offers intro courses and tutorials to beginners how to move data, basic command line tools etc., and often it is a good place to find answers very specific to your system (eg how the X forward etc). You may want to check out with your center.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I prefer to just download the data from the remote disks and then do the plots on my own local machine, which has all of my favorite tools for post-processing my data.

I understand that this can be inconvenient though. It is indeed possible to run a GUI on a remote supercomputer though, if you first use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` when signing into the remote machine (The  [difference between the `-X` and `-Y` options](//askubuntu.com/a/35518/676348) is the degree of trust you give the X11 clients). The reason I don't usually do this, is because viewing on my local computer, a GUI that's running on a remote machine, can sometimes be painfully slow, but this will depend on many factors (speeds of the internet connections involved, age of the hardware involved, etc.), so you might at least like to try it once. From a Windows computer, you can run an X11 server such as [Xming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xming).

Personally though, I watch my data as it's being calculated, using the `awk` command; and if I want to make a publication-quality plot, I download the data to my local machine and do all post-processing and/or plotting offline. If you post the exact output from VASP and what precise numbers you want in your plot/visualization (with a question title like "how can I visualize the following data from the command line?"), I can try to give you an `awk` command that would work for your case.

Comment: Could you tell me more about how to use the `awk` to watch the data as it is being calculated, I am not sure how to do it? And is it necessary that I tar all the data into a single file before I download them?

Comment: @Jack It's not necessary to `tar` all the data into one file, but it can have some benefits (speed of file transfer often being one of them). If you ask a new question  about using `awk` command to watch data, and you provide your specific output file and which numbers in it that you want to watch, I can try to help you. Today is a holiday in my country (Thanksgiving in Canada) so I might not be able to reply immediately, but I'll try to reply as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will also try to organize my need and make it neat. I really appreciate your kindly help, Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: @Jack I watch my data during calculation using `tail -f yourlogfilename.log`

Comment: @NikeDattani In some cases downloading output files could become cumbersome especially, if you HPC admin has setup some security measures that might prevent upload and download of heavy files from the remote instance.

Comment: @Jack the `less +F filename` command will print the last lines of your file in the terminal. Also the command `grep "Pattern you need to search" PATH_TO_FILE` will search the file for the keywords and output all the lines including that keyword. Also the `grep` is a powerful tool which you can use to search a file for keywords and print the same line, n number of preceding or following lines etc. For this case I recommend that you try searching for examples to use grep. Also note that adding a `| tee NEWLOG` after whatever the command would save your display output to a file `NEWLOG`.

Answer (score 13):

It would probably be easier to use some software such as [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). It allows you to select the location on your remote system and synchronise with the local system by matching either the time stamp or size (and probably other properties). Also if you are using Linux, read the answers on this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299412/is-there-any-winscp-equivalent-for-linux) to get an idea of alternatives. This way you can visually manipulate the required files in a manner much similar to what is done in a tutorial.

Note: If possible, ask the system administrator to install [xrdp](http://xrdp.org/) (and other required packages which I am sure he would know) which is similar to Windows [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) and allows you to connect to a GUI instance of the server.

Answer (score 5):

To address your specific question: **No**, you don't always have to download everything locally. VASP creates a lot of different output files and sometimes (most of the times?) you only need some of those. So you can **delete** large output files you don't need in your study right after the calculation on the cluster and then download only the necessary files.